# Spring MVC Web service GET (Rest) call : 404

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement simple web service that takes userId and shows some user rated info information on HTML web page.

I tried to write some spring annotation based web service using spring mvc

When I tried to run following program, I got 404 error.

http://localhost:8080/EdgeStore/execute/user1

Its simple program that I have written. 
Am I missing something in this program ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="EdgeStore"/>

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    </beans>
```

and dispatcher is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  
    xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"  
    version="2.4">

   <display-name>EdgeStore</display-name>
     <servlet>
          <servlet-name>EdgeStore</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>EdgeStore</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

And Controller is

```
package EdgeStore;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/execute")
    public class executeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserProfile getUserProfile(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setUserId(userId);
        userProfile.setSegmentId("defaultSegement");
        return userProfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: thanks Patrick, I tried both "/*" and "/EdgeStore"...Both not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your dispatcher in this format and try :

```
 <display-name>EdgeStore</display-name>
     <servlet>
          <servlet-name>EdgeStore</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
// Give location for your config file.
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>EdgeStore</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

If this doesn't work, let me know. I will remove my answer.

Comment: Can you package your project without the important data and send it. I can check out here faster what's the issue. Lemme know.

Comment: You can access package here

Comment: Why are you not using maven, rather than adding the JAR's in classpath.

Comment: Recently moved from C to Java :) Planning to use gradle going ahead

Comment: Do you want me to remove JARs from package for size reason ?

Comment: Start with maven first.. Maven is more suited for webapps and more help will come for that. Secondly I found Gradle is slow...

Comment: Thanks Bhau for help